# Shadow in android without elevation (allow clicks through <Modal>?) (elevated's respect zIndex?)

Tags: android, react-native

On Android, I use `elevation` extensively. The only reason I use it though is to get a shadow. However I am now encountering a problem with zIndex of a button.

My bottom nav bar has elevation of 4:

```
<View style={[styles.bottomNav, { elevation:4 }]}>
   { /* ... */ }
</View>
<View style={[styles.button, { elevation:2 }] />
```

I then have an absolutely position circle element, that I want to show over this bar. If elevation is 2 of the button, it does not show over, I have to set it to 4+. However elevation of 4 is when it is when on press.

So to get around this I wrapped my button in a transparent `<Modal>` like this:

```
<View style={[styles.bottomNav, { elevation:4 }]}>
   { /* ... */ }
</View>
<Modal onRequestClose={()=>null} transparent>
    <View style={[styles.button, { elevation:2 }] />
</Modal>
```

Now the button shadow is perfect, at whatever elevation of the button. It is always over the bar. HOWEVER the problem is that clicks are not passing through the `<Modal>`

I even tried putting a View within the Modal and setting its `pointerEvents="box-none"` (this trick works for `TouchableNativeFeedback`)

```
<Modal onRequestClose={()=>null} transparent>
    <View style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} pointerEvents="box-none">
        <View style={[styles.button, { elevation:2 }] />
    </View>
</Modal>
```

However this is still not allowing the press events through the modal.

**Is there a way to allow the pointer events through the modal? OR is there any other way to get a shadow on Android which respects `zIndex`?**

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a panresponder. Try adding onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture and onResponderTerminationRequest props to modal. Like:

```
        <Modal onRequestClose={()=>null} transparent
           onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture={(evt, gestureState) => false}
           onResponderTerminationRequest={() => false}
        >
        <View style={{width:'100%', height:'100%'}} pointerEvents="box-none">
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>console.log(`Test`)} style={{ elevation:2 }}>
            <Text>Button!</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    </Modal>
```

More info: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder

Comment: Interesting thank you I will try this out and share. I am busy though so won't be trying this for some time.